# Shockwave Player in Chromium?

Tags: chromium, plugins

Is there a Ubuntu 10.04-compatible version of Shockwave Player to run on the Chromium browser?

Answer (score 2):

Shockwave player was never released for Linux (only for Windows, OSX & Mac OS 9) only Flash was.